# View in fragments cannot be applied to ()

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-fragments, android-studio

I am trying to hide my fragment when its not on the screen so i used   `setUserVisibleHint`    to hide my fragment but i am getting an error

> "myUIUpdate (View) in GamesFragment cannot be applied  to ()"

How do i resolve it?

Here is my activity:

```
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
  import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
  import android.view.KeyEvent;
  import android.view.LayoutInflater;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.ViewGroup;
  import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
  import android.webkit.WebView;
  import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
  import android.widget.ProgressBar;

   public class GamesFragment extends Fragment {

private ProgressBar progress;
private WebView myWebView;



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_games, null);
    return rootView;

}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    myUIUpdate(view);
}





void myUIUpdate(View view) {

    String url = "http://gsmarena.com";
    myWebView = (WebView)this.getView().findViewById(R.id.webViewGames);
    myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new myWebViewClient());
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    progress = (ProgressBar) this.getView().findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    myWebView.loadUrl(url);
    progress.setMax(100);


    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView View, String url) {
            View.loadUrl(url);
            GamesFragment.this.progress.setProgress(0);
            return true;
        }

    });


    myWebView.setOnKeyListener(new android.view.View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override

        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            WebView webView = (WebView) v;

            switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                        webView.goBack();
                        return true;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        return false;
        }
    });

}


private class myWebViewClient extends WebChromeClient {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
        GamesFragment.this.setValue(newProgress);
        super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
    }
}

boolean isResumed = false;
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser); {
            if (isVisibleToUser && isResumed()) {
                myUIUpdate();
                isResumed = true;
    }


    }}




public void setValue(int progress) {
    this.progress.setProgress(progress);
}


}
```

To be precise error comes in this line:

```
 boolean isResumed = false;
 @Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser); {
            if (isVisibleToUser && isResumed()) {
              // here is the error.
                myUIUpdate();
                isResumed = true;
    }


    }}
```

I have tried changing

```
 myUIUpdate();
```

to

```
 myUIUpdate(View);
```

When i try to do that it says"expression expected".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get to Fragment's View you can use `Fragment.getView(`) and pass it to your `myUiUpdate`

Comment: Can you give me an example please?

Comment: try myUpdate(getView()) in your setUserVisibleHint